# Tkinter not running on updated python

Tags: python-3, tkinter

So, I'm trying to use a project, that uses tkinter on my Raspberry Pi but I have an issue.
I needed an updated version of Python, so I updated it to 3.7.4, however, when I try to `import tkinter`, it gives me the error message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'`. Tkinter also gives the message `If this fails, your Python may not be configured for Tk`. Other modules import as usual.
How can I configure Python to use Tk? Thank you, in advance, for any help.

`python3 -m tkinter` gives the same error message as trying to import it.
I tried `sudo apt-get install python-tk` and `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` but it says it's already the latest version and doesn't do anything.
I then uninstalled and reinstalled tkinter but that didn't help.

I updated Python by running these commands (I have wiped the system and done it again, but same issue):

```
cd ~
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.4/Python-3.7.4.tgz
tar -zxvf Python-3.7.4.tgz
cd Python-3.7.4
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Is tkinter installed? What does `python3 -m tkinter` give you?

Comment: Your problem is probably caused by **so I updated it to 3.7.4**. How?

Comment: @Tom Boddaert, I am using Rpi4B buster release 2019sep26 Thonny 3.2 python 3.7.3 (/usr/bin/python3).  I tried this: >>> import tkinter returns >>>.  Your problem is NOT specific to tkinter. PS - I have not installed tkinter beforehand.

Comment: @Milliways Thank you, I have updated the post to elaborate.

Comment: @tlfong01 Thank you for the suggestion but can you please elaborate on what you mean by it's not specific to tkinter, all other modules that don't use tkinter, that I have tried, work.

Comment: @Tom Boddaert, First of all, let me confess that I am a Windows guy and hate to use the less linux terminal commands I know how to use.  I used to tell me sad story that not too many years ago I followed the instructions to install a software package, using "wget", "tar", "make" etc.  It was the first time I heard of "wget", and I didn't know how to use Windows to unzip "tar" files.  I also did not know about why some "local" files must use "./" in front of the file name, and there are "aliases" which are "nick names" where you cannot find the directory, ...

Comment: Fast forward to a year ago, when I was using Rpi3B+ and Python 3.7.3.  I needed to upgrade to python 3.7.4 for a tensorFlow package.  If I remember correctly, I first use pip (or pip3, I forgot, because I did not know pip and pip3 are different, and might install the package in different directories for python2 or python3 (at that time I think there are python2 and python3 in different directories, and if your run python2 or python3 programs, you must use "sudo pyton2 myprogram" and "sudo python3 myprogram", ...

Comment: I did not know that my bash command sees "python2" or "python3" as a bash command to run a "script" which is actually the python program "script" the first line of which is a "comment" which tells bash guy which python2 or python3 "environment", containing relevant modules to import, must go to before start running the program.  Anyway, back to point where I was upgrading from python 3.7.3 to 3.7.4.  The instruction actually tells me to set up an "environment" (the first time I heard this name).  Anyway, my installed package could not start (cannot find module to import, or something) ...

Comment: I did not know where I did wrong when using pip.  So I used another install tool call "npm" or something to install python 3.7.4.  But no luck again. Then I used another installation tools call "cell.." (forgot exact name).  Then one more installation package (forgot name).  Every time I used a new raspbian jessie/stretch image (I have 50+ micro SD cards in my card holder).  At last I concluded that perhaps I missed something import (like there should be no space before the "=" symbol in a statement).  But I could not find where the installed python3 programs stays (still don't know "aliases")

Comment: So I gave up, after struggling for perhaps 5 hours, and decided to come back when Rpi4B arrives.  Now I have Rpi4B, buster, and Thonny.  IDLE as gone, but I can also use Geany.  Thank you for reading my long sad story.  Now the thing you might find useful: (1) I found some program which can run in Thonny CANNOT run in Geany, (2) Other guys complain that they could not run their python program but I could run in Thonny, but not in Geany.  So Thonny is my best friend.

Comment: One more case (not sure if I guess correctly) is that one guy uses HAT which Rpi talks to the HAT when booting and setup some config.  The guy cannot run in terminal mode, but I am run in Thonny, but not in Geany.  I told you my background in my introduction, because I need to warn you that I am make some guesses which might be wrong and lead you to a dark alley, ... This is the end of my story.  In case I remember more relevant things, I would tell you later.  Good luck and cheers.

Comment: PS - In case your are curious, I am writing my story for two reasons: (1) To look back my failures and see if I can find a pattern to use for the future, (2) To practise my use of English.  - End of my story -

Comment: Just fiddling with your question is unlikely to get any answers. Frankly I doubt there is any significant difference between the Debian 3.7.3 and 3.7.4
In the standard the module is in /usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/. Include the output of 

`import sys
print(sys.version)
print(sys.path)`

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if it is installed use the **terminal** as Dougie stated in the comments.

If it's not installed type in the terminal

`sudo apt-get install python3-tk`

Testing in python shell

>>>`import tkinter`

>>>`tkinter._test()`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it just says that it's already the latest version and doesn't do anything but"python3 -m tkinter" produces the same error as trying to import it.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling it, then reinstalling.

Comment: Yes both tkinter and raspian

Comment: Check to see if it's placing the library in the right folder. In Terminal                                                  ```cd /usr/local/lib/python3.7```                                               Then list the files                                                                                      ```ls```

Answer (score 1):

**python -m tkinter** quite correctly reports **No module named tkinter** because the Python2 version is **Tkinter**

`python -m Tkinter` should work!

There is no need to install tkinter, because it should be included in python3.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the 3, I did run "python3 -m tkinter" and got an error